# How to get the first row that is data free in Excel using Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, loops, xlsx

I need to get the first row that is free of data of an Excel worksheet, in order to write on it from the code.

I have this example:
[image]

The code should output the numbers 6 or 8 (does not matter, they are both fine), because each of them represent the row that is free of data, and is able to be written.

I tried this code:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++){
    if (xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(shoopingWorksheet["!rows"] === " ")){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

but it is not really the proper way to do this, nor it is working...

So the steps are: [in Node.js]

1. Iterate through all the rows (first column is enough).
2. Verify whether that each A[i] is empty.
3. If it empty, then print it (console.log(i)).

So, how do I iterate through all the rows, on their first column, and verify if that tab is free of data?

Comment: sheet_to_json() will ignore empty rows. I have edited the answer, which will return Undefined when no data is present

Answer (score 1):

you are using `sheet_to_json()` wrongly. It will take sheet name as an argument and returns a list of rows as objects.

Following code might help you.

```
const XlsxPopulate = require("xlsx-populate");
XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync(ExcelPath).then((workbook) => {
    const worksheet = workbook.sheet('Sheet1');
    for (let index = 1; index < 10; index++) {
        const signal = worksheet
        .row(index)
        .cell(1)
        .value();
        if(signal==undefined){
            console.log(signal)
        }
       
        
    }
```

Please refer this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-populate). It has examples to edit the excel file as well